# LaTeX - Misplaced alignment tab character &

Tags: document-classes

I am struggling with LaTeX, which is a template by the American Institute of Physics. I work on a document with header:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}


\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

It seems that it works fine as long as I don't type the following command:

```
\[    
{\mathbf{sign}{(d)}}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
-1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\]
```

where the compilation of the pdf file fails saying: `Misplaced alignment tab character &`.

As far as I understand the most common solution to this problem would be to insert `\usepackage{amsmath}`. The problem is that when I do so the compilation fails again, only this time the following error pops up:

`LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual`.

All in all I have problems compiling the pdf file when I use 
`\usepackage{amsmath}` no matter the `cases` command from the above. Everything I tried so far did not resolve the issue.

If anyone has ever crashed into this, please share experience and possibly a way of solving it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `amsmath` is not a document class, but a *package*. In addition, I suggest loading `mathtools` which is an extension of `amsmath`, and use its `cases*` environment. The 2nd column is automatically in text mode.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo of me. I edited the post.

Comment: As the class loads `txfonts` and its excellent font glyphs, loading `amsmath` later causes issues due to LaTeX absence of namespace. You can fix this by doing `\let\iint\relax`, `\let\iiint\relax`, `\let\iiiint\relax`, `\let\idotsint\relax` before loading `amsmath`. Notice that `amsmath` is clever enough to avoid similar problems with `stix` package, but alas not with `txfonts` package. But probably `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` before loading the class is simpler (and the `txfonts` `\idotsint` is much better than amsmath's one!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem seems to result from the loading of `txfonts`  by the class. It is solved if you replace line  98 of the .cls file:

```
\usepackage{txfonts,graphicx}
```

with

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{txfonts}}
```

and this code  will compile smoothly:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\mathbf{sign}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sgn(d) =
\begin{cases*}
1, & if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even, \\
-1, & if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is odd.
\end{cases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* : as far as I know, `txfonts` is deprecated in favour of the couple of packages `newtxtext, newtxmath`.

Comment: @ Bernard, Thank you! Your post solved my problem, now it all works fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the `aip-cp` class. With the simple document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[    
{\mathbf{sign}{(d)}}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
-1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

the error is

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.8 1, &
         \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
```

followed by

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 1, & \text
              {if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
```

The fact is that the `cases` environment is not defined in standard LaTeX (which has a `\cases` command inherited by plain TeX). You have to add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

that will also provide `\text`.

I also recommend defining a `\sign` command (which appears to be an operator):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{\mathbf{sign}}

\begin{document}

\[    
\sign(d)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
-1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your case, though, the class loads `txfonts`, which is a big nuisance, because it is an obsolete package that has problems with `amsmath`. The solution is to load `amsmath` *before* the class.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{\mathbf{sign}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sign(d)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is even}, \\
-1, & \text{if the number of indices $k$ satisfying $d_k=a_k$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The point is that I cannot change document class to {article}, but stick to {aip-cp} and when apply \usepackage{amsmath} the LaTeX error from my post occurs. I am aware that under \documentclass{article} everything works fine, there is no problem with {cases}.

Comment: @Candidate Just change `article` to `aip-cp`: the purpose of the example is to show what you have to modify, that is add `\usepackage{amsmath}`. I added a final part.

Comment: With \documentclass{aip-cp} it does not work. That was my problem from the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: @Candidate One hopes that document classes keep up with the development of LaTeX packages, but apparently they don't. Fixed.